# Easy way to add 3 different types of Objects to one ArrayList with one method?

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, subclass

This is a copy from an assignment I've done, so apologizes for some of the Norwegian commenting.

My question is:
I have an items ArrayList which holds Objects from the classes Item, Swords, Potions.  (Potions & Swords are subclasses of Items).  And I have 3 different methods to add these Objects to the ArrayList.

My question is Simple actually.  Is there a (simple, I'm new and learning still) way for me to add all Items and Subclasses of Item to the ArrayList without having 3 different methods which look all alike.  (addItem, addSword, addPotion), all close to the bottom of the code.

I'd want something like this ( not thought through, just wrote something)

```
public void addItem(String typeofItem){
    item = new typeofItem;
    items.add(item);
}
```

There is alot more to the code, but i feel like this is whats relevant.

```
public class Player
{
    // Fields -------
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private int health;
    private ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    private Item item;
    private Swords sword;
    private Potions potion;
    private Checker valid;
    private int maxCarry;
    private int gold;
    private int currentWeight;
    // ----------------

    /**
     * Klassens konstruktør. Players health vil alltid settes til 100.
     * 
     * @param name         Player navn
     * @param type         Player type
     * @param goldValue    Players starting gold
     * @param setMaxWeight Players max carry weight
     */
    public Player (String name, String type, int goldValue, int setMaxWeight) {
        valid = new Checker();                       // Creates a checker object to do String and integer checks

        this.name = valid.checkString(name);         // Setter player name, etter å ha sjekka at den ikke er tom
        this.type = checkType(type);                 // Setter type, etter å ha processet den
        health = 100;                                // Health skal alltid starte som 100
        maxCarry  = valid.checkInt(setMaxWeight);    // Sets max carry weight
        currentWeight = 0;                           // Start vekten til player 
        gold = valid.checkInt(goldValue);            // setter goldbeholding etter å ha sjekka at den ikke er negativ
    }

    /**
     * En metode for å selge ett Item objekt, reduserer gold og øker weight ved kjøp.
     * 
     * @param item        Item object to sell
     */
    private void buyItem(Item item)
    {
        // Temporary values given from items methods getweight and getvalue to be used in a mutation
        int tempWeight;
        int tempValue;
        tempWeight = item.getWeight();
        tempValue = item.getValue();
        // Checks if the item meets te conditions to be bought (enough gold, and can be carried)
        if (checkConditions(tempValue, tempWeight)) {
            // Adds the item to ArrayList if conditions met and updates gold and weight
            items.add(item);
            currentWeight += tempWeight;
            gold -= tempValue;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to calculate if given value and weight is accepted to perform a purchase (total gold > 0 && total weight < maxWeight)
     * 
     * @param value     Gold value of item
     * @param weight    Weight of item
     * @return boolean  Returns true if conditions met 
     */
    private boolean checkConditions(int value, int weight)
    {
        if (!(gold >= value))
        {
            System.out.println("You don't have enough gold!");
            return false;
        } else {
            if (!(weight + currentWeight <= maxCarry)){
                System.out.println("You'll be too heavy carry this item!");
                return false;
            } else {
                // All conditions met
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adds an item to player inventory (uses method buyItem to process the item as a purchase)
     * 
     * @param itemName    String to name item
     * @param itemDesc    String to describe item
     * @param itemValue   int to declare items value
     * @param itemWeight  int to declare items Weight
     * @param itemAction  String to give item an action
     */
    public void addItem(String itemName, String itemDesc, int itemValue, int itemWeight, String itemAction)
    {
        // A Player generated item, which needs all parameters to specify it
        item = new Item(itemName, itemDesc, itemValue, itemWeight, itemAction);
        buyItem(item);
    }

    /**
     * Randomly generates a Sword object and adds it to players inventory (uses buyItem to process)
     * @see Swords#Swords
     */
    public void addSword()
    {
        sword = new Swords();
        buyItem(sword);
    }

    /**
     * Randomly generates a Potion object and adds it to players inventory (uses buyItem to process)
     * @see Potions#Potions
     */
    public void addPotion()
    {
        potion = new Potions();
        buyItem(potion);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create something called a Factory class. A factory class's responsibility is to generate instances of a type of item for you.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm

Essentially you wrap the method you talk about in a class and return a new instance of that object.

```
public class ItemFactory{

    public static Item addItem(String typeofItem){
        switch(typeofItem){
             case "Sword":
                return new Sword();
             case "Potion":
                return new Potion();
             ...
            default:
               //put any code here that is like the "else" of an if-else block
              return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Then when you need to add a new item of a specific type:

```
buyItem(ItemFactory.addItem("Sword"));
```

Comment: Would this create a new object of the instanced item?  I want the Swords/potions/items in general to be an object that can be moved between the player and shops at a later stage. And have multiple instances of each.  As in, wont i need a sword = new Sword(); for it to be an independent object

Comment: They are stored in the items arraylist. If you ever need to access them you can do so from this list. The only reason you would need to use a sword variable is if you need to keep track if a very specific sword vs all available sword. For example. if you needed to keep track of the current/player's sword. However if you had 2 different swords, then every time you called addSword it would override whatever was in the sword variable with the new one, so you would have to access it from the array list anyways.

Comment: I added this, I'm however not too familiar with switches yet.  what do i return if none of the conditions are met, and how do i write it?  Something like, return new Potion();} else {return null;}?

Comment: If you're not returning anything use in a case, use a break instead of a return. If you expect that a situation will occur where no cases match. Have a default at the end instead of a case.  I will update the answer with an example. You can use an if-else block instead of a switch if you're more comfortable with that syntax. They are essentially the same. Switches are just more readable but if-else blocks allow you more flexibility in what you're checking for.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help!  I assume I want to break it, as if it cant find the name it shouldn't add anything to the players inventory (like a null)

Comment: No, sorry if I confused you. Don't "break" unless you specifically have more code after the switch statement you want to run. It's just very common to see breaks; in there to prevent something called "fall through" where all the cases below the matching case runs. However return statements work the same way as a break in the example above. You'll want to use the "default" which is the equivalent of the "else" block.

Comment: "deleted old", just read the last response and understood the problem, and fixed it. Again thank you works flawlessly now!

Comment: Don't use the "break" example. Just add the default: return null;. The break was confusing so I'll remove it from the example, but when you have time look up switch cases so you know how they properly work and how to prevent "fall through"